# How do I check for specific date format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having issues with dates. The problem is, ISDATE will give me dates that are valid even though the format is different. However, what I would like to do is INSERT NULL is any date field not formatted like: *8/28/2013 or 08/28/2013*

This is for international use. And for U.S Use only. This means: 08/08/2013 will mean August 8th 2011. And Will Cast as 2011-08-08.

I am not sure how to check for the format. I can do the whole CASE WHEN.

I tried playing around like this:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';
SELECT CASE WHEN @d != FORMAT ( @d, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'en-US' ) THEN @d ELSE NULL END
```

The dates currently in the column are format like so. *8/28/2013 or 08/28/2013*
And I would do a cast if the format is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming the column _is not_ a `date`/`datetime` column? otherwise this question would be moot since the format isn't actually preserved, just the information behind it. (or you're looking at how SQL default formats the column when cast to a string/displayed)

Comment: It is a date but the APP validation is non-existent, so dates are entered like: 0808/21/20133, think of the worse possible entries. I am trying to clean up some historical data.

Comment: How would you determine if 08/09/2013 is correct? Is it 8th Sep 2013 or 9th Aug 2013?

Comment: What about 6/8/2013, or is it 8/6/2013, or not, maybe...

Comment: 0808/21/20133, cannot possibly be a date.

Comment: Again I am working with TEXT files and doing dumps I did not write that stuff.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy So when you claim it is a "date", what you mean is "it's just a bunch of text"!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're taking a `datetime` column, purposely casting it to a string (thus formatting it) then looking for instances where it would *not* adhere to that format.

Truth is, the format is only relevant when *you* make it. SQL isn't storing it as "01/01/2013" or "1/1/2013"--it's only displayed using the default cast or a format *you've provided*.

So, as-is, the question is moot. You're not going to find an abnormality in the data, just instances where you didn't get the format you wanted.

In regards to sanitization, when SQL goes to INSERT/UPDATE (and the format's bad [you mentioned `0808/21/20133`]) you'll get something like:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I don't follow your view: I am working with historical data in CSV and text files. long story short, the conversion is failing because of these formats. Thought the explanation was very simple.

Comment: So how does parsing through a CSV equate to performing a maintenance on a `datetime` column in SQL? (Maybe I'm the one confused?)

Answer (score -1):

You can store the date as varchar, then the format with the following query:

```
DECLARE @d varchar(10) 
set @d= '08/28/2013';
SELECT CASE WHEN @d LIKE '[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN @d ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: The above does not work, it throws a conversion error if I do: 08/28/20133, I need to simply get a NULL rather than the error. Anyway thanks for your help and time.

Comment: I think extending the variable size would resolve the issue.

Comment: I think storing dates as varchar is a horrible idea.

Comment: @DanBracuk:   Here, the user is saying that the user could insert any date which could not be in date format,and I don't have any idea how to store values like ''08/28/20133' in datetime type of variable.